# mod_rewrite apache to lighttpd rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

Having some trouble converting what appears to be a simple rewrite rule in apache .htaccess to a lighttpd rule.

The apache rule:
`RewriteRule (.*) index.php?baseURL=$1 [L,QSA]`

Essentially, the URL in its entirety is passed as `baseURL` parameter, and of course any other given parameters are preserved.

One caveat is that it should only apply to a single directory, and (hopefully) not include that directory in `baseURL`.

Currently what I have in lighttpd is:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
"^\/Folder\/(.*)" => "/Folder/index.php?baseURL=$0"
)
```

This gets the entire url and passes it as a parameter, including `\Folder\` and the parameters, so `http://domain/Folder/test.php?someParam=1` makes `baseURL` contain `/Folder/test.php?someParam=1`

I can parse this in php and make it work, but the point is to have the same php code in apache and lighttpd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple problems. `$0` is the entire match, you want `$1` referencing the first submatch, the `(.*)`. Like so:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/Folder/(.*)" => "/Folder/index.php?baseURL=$1"
)
```

This still has a problem with the query string, it'll produce two `?`s. E.g.

```
"/Folder/foo?bar=1" => "/Folder/index.php?baseURL=foo?bar=1"
```

Final solution:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    # Match when there are no query variables
    "^/Folder/([^\?]*)$" => "/Folder/index.php?baseURL=$1",
    # Match query variables and append with &
    "^/Folder/([^\?]*)\?(.*)$" => "/Folder/index.php?baseURL=$1&$2",
)
```

Comment: The second `?` would get encoded-decoded properly. That is why OP had no problems in receiving `/Folder/test.php?someParam=1` as `baseURL` value.

Comment: Ah, okay. I get your solution now. This is how `[QSA]` would have worked so you're correct. +1

Comment: @RaviThapliyal What is `[QSA]`?

Comment: [QSA] causes the query string to be preserved properly and automatically through the rewrite.

Comment: It looks like the first rule works perfectly, but the second produces a 404.

Comment: @SuperJer I meant I didn't know the abbreviation, "QSA" on google gets you Qualified Security Assessor. I see now, googled "QSA query string" and it is query string append flag. (I am not very familiar with apache).

Comment: My mistake!  I snuck in a typo in place of `Folder` when pasting in your example.  Works perfectly!